# Why has the quotation markup changed?

Tags: discussion, design

Since a week or two, the vaguely yellow background (reminiscent of Post-it notes - see the sidebar to the right → ) of `>` quotes has changed. Does anyone know why?
It's currently a lot harder to distinguish them from regular text, and I would personally like to see that change reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change was made to the entire Stack Exchange network, not just Arqade. This [Meta announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/370674) should answer some of your questions, and provide a place to ask the unanswered ones.

Comment: It's funny how the top voted comments there makes a point similar to mine. I don't really understand the reasons for changing it in the first place: they want to dissuade users from using blockquotes to highlight images, improve visibility of blockquotes, and prevent  "theming issues", highlighting differences between "quotes, spoilers and code". But this just renders quotations less visible. Anyway, I should bring that up there. Thanks!